# coldfusion MSFT SQL Image Store

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 10 and working on new project where the user will be allowed to upload pictures from events.  Never worked with user uploaded images before.  How  do I store the image in MSFT SQL?  Is there a best practice when it comes to users uploading huge 10 MEG pictures?  Is there a way to control or automatically compress pictures?

Thanks!

Comment: My suggestion would be to NOT store the actual image in the database. Just store the name or the path to the file in the database and store the actual image on a file server.

Answer (score 1):

This is a two part question:

**Part 1:**

First part will be your data store and pull.  Where you will use in your cfquery, cfqueryparam that will look like this:

```
INSERT into EMPLOYEES (FirstName,LastName,Photo)
VALUES ('Aiden','Quinn',<cfqueryparam value="#ImageGetBlob(myImage)#" cfsqltype='cf_sql_blob'>)
```

To select then reconstruct you will use this:

```
<cfset myImage = ImageNew(#GetBLOBs.PHOTO#)>
```

Where you can then do this:

```
<img src='#myImage#>
```

[Above examples pulled from the docs.](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_h-im_23.html)

Get familiar with `<cfimage>` and cfscript version `image()` for editing (rotating, scaling, etc.)

**Part 2:**

The other part to your question has to do with upload limits.

Coldfuion has limits that can be changed in CFIDE or RAILO equivalent. There is also limiters set in your web service like apache and IIS, you will have to look into this to change it.

BUT if you are only concerned about 10 mb size images you will be fine.  It is when you get into hundreds of MB size files that will cause you headaches.

Remember on your form to set your form enctype to this because you will have to upload your file to your server before you can work with it:

```
<form action="workPage.cfm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also you will have to access that file using `<cffile>`

I think all this is enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the storage size of an image, and this is of course a reasonable concern, then you could use  to scale the image down to the maximum dimensions and quality or compression level (if stored as a jpeg) that you need within your application.

Storing your images within a database allows them to be more easily portable, across a cluster for instance. If that is not a concern, then what I tend to do is generate a unique name for each image uploaded, rename them, and store the unique name in the database rather than the image itself.